# Prove $\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{\lVert u +hv \rVert_{\infty} - \lVert u \rVert_{\infty}}{h}=\max_{x \in M}(v\cdot \operatorname{sign}(u))$

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces, frechet-derivative, gateaux-derivative

I have posted this question before but did not get any answer so im trying again:

> Let $u,v \in C[a,b]$ and $M=\{x \in [a,b]: \lVert u  \rVert_{\infty} = |u(x)| \}$. The Gâteaux derivative of the supremum norm $\lVert \cdot  \rVert_{\infty}$ evaluated at $u$ in the direction of $v$ is:
>
> $$\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{\lVert u +hv \rVert_{\infty} - \lVert u  \rVert_{\infty}}{h}=\max_{x \in M}(v(x)\cdot \operatorname{sign}(u(x)))$$

I'm trying to prove this but do not get anywhere. I do not find any site mentioning this equation either. Any tips? I'm fine with a reference that proves this. Thanks

Comment: I'd start out considering the case where $u$ is everywhere nonnegative, because the whole "sign" thing is clearly just to handle that bit. You might also want to use a bit more notation to show how the $x$ over which you're taking a max actually appears in the right hand side.

Comment: I already considered that, did not get anywhere but ill try again more precisely. Concerning the notation, check my edit. Thats what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The nice thing about $u \ge 0$ is that the right hand side becomes just $\max_{x \in M} v(x)$, i.e. $\|v\|_\infty$.

Comment: Not necessarily as i understand it. The set $M$ containts the x values for $u$, not $v$.

Comment: Right...I should have left off the "i.e." part, but got ahead of myself.

Answer (score 1):

For some particular $h$, suppose that the max of $u + hv$ occurs at some point $c$ that is not in $M$. Let $b$ be a point of $M$, and let $A = \|u\|_\infty$, to save typing. Then 
$$
(u+hv)(b) = A + h v(b)\\
(u+hv)(c) = u(c) + hv(c)
$$
where $u(c) < A$ (because $c \notin M$). I claim that for small enough $h$, the first of these will be larger than the second (i.e., even if a non-$M$ point like $c$ is the max for some $h$, for small enough $h$ it will  not be). Here's the argument:

Let $L = A - u(c) > 0$,  Then we have that, for any $h$ now, 
$$
(u+hv)(b) - (u+hv)(c) = A - u(c) + h (v(b) - v(c))
$$
If we pick $h$ so that $L/2 > |h(v(b) - v(c))|$, then we get that 
$$
(u+hv)(b) - (u+hv)(c) = L + h (v(b) - v(c)) \ge \frac{L}{2} > 0.
$$
So for any point $c \notin M$, we see that for small enough $h$, 
$$
(u+hv)(c) < (u+hv)(b)
$$
Hence the abscissa of maximum value of $u+hv$, as $h$ tends to $0$, must be in the set $M$. For some point $b \in M$, that will have the form 
$$
(u + hv)(b) = L + hv(b)
$$
When we subtract from this the value $\| u\|_\infty = L$, we get a numerator $hv(b)$;dividing by $h$, we get $v(b)$.

Thus the limit must be $v(b)$ for some $b \in M$. Looking back at the expression
$$
(u + hv)(b) = L + hv(b)
$$
where $b$ ranges over all point of $M$, the largest value this can take occurs where $v(b)$ is largest. In particular, the limit on the left is just $\max{x \in M} v(x)$, as required.

[I've assumed here that $u, v \ge 0$, to avoid dealing with more absolute values, etc.]

Comment: I have a similar proof for when both are positive, but im lost when trying to prove it in general... do you have any link where they go trough this in detail?

Comment: No --- I just thought up this one on the spur of the moment.